# PHP if array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and when I print the output like so `print_r($userExists);`

it returns `Array ( )` I wrote this code to tell me if the array is empty or not:

```
if(isset($userExists)){
        echo 'exists';
    }else{
        echo 'does not exists';
    }
```

But regardless if the array is empty or not, it only returns `exists` What Am i doing wrong, when the array is populated, it looks like this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 10 ) )`

Comment: even an empty array is set. YOu can check with count($userExists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
if( !empty( $userExists ) ) {
    echo 'exists';
}
else {
    echo 'does not exists';
}
```

or

```
if( count( $userExists ) ) {
    echo 'exists';
}
else {
    echo 'does not exists';
}
```

However is safer to use `empty()` as if that variable doesn't exists your script will not stop due to `exception` while `count()` does.

`isset` is "not working"* here since this variable is setted (so exists) even if is empty.

So, basically, `isset` will

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

---

Last but not least, if you want to know which is "better" for code optimization, I could tell you a little "secret": `count()` doesn't need to traverse the array each time to know how many elements will be there since, internally, it store the elements number (as you can see under), so every call to `count()` function results in `O(1)` complexity.

```
ZEND_API int zend_hash_num_elements(const HashTable *ht)
{
    IS_CONSISTENT(ht);

    return ht->nNumOfElements;
}
```

`zend_hash_num_elements` is called from `count()` (take a look [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3/ext/standard/array.c#L300))

from [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

*(not working as you wish/need)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `count($userExists)` will produce an error if `$userExists` hasn't been set, whereas `empty($userExists)` won't.

Comment: @Styphon As I keep on telling you, it has been firmly established that the variable *does* exist, otherwise `print_r` would be throwing an error already and not giving back an empty array.

Comment: @Styphon: yes, you're right. I was updating my answer :)

Comment: You wanted to type `!empty` instead of `empty` in the first line of the code, didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

use as below

```
if(isset($userExists) && count($userExists) > 0 ){
        echo 'exists';
    }else{
        echo 'does not exists';
    }
```

OR

You can check if the variable is an array and having some value

```
if(is_array($userExists) && count($userExists) > 0 ){
    echo 'exists';
}else{
    echo 'does not exists';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$userExists = array();
```

The variable exists, and it is set. That's what `isset` tests for.

What you want is:

```
if( $userExists) echo "exists";
```

Comment: @Styphon But I just established that it does exist, and so did OP by using `print_r` on it.

Comment: But you're ignoring the else, when it doesn't exist. When it doesn't exist that code will throw an error. That is bad advice to give the OP.

Comment: @Styphon ... huh? OP used `print_r` to debug a variable, which means we *know* it exists. I left off the `else echo "doesn't exist"` for brevity, since it's not important to the test itself.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an extra check for if!

```
if($array){
// Will execute only if there is any value inside of the array
}
```

By using if there is no need checking if any value is available!
you are using 'isset' for variables that might not exist like $_GET value or $_SESSION etc....
'empty' to check a string value

by php documentation empty works only in string and not arrays